# Error with component selectors when using transpiled npm package with Emotion in a different repository

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, babeljs, emotion

In repository application (A), the Emotion module is not directly used in the component. Instead, it is imported through a different folder structure. Here's an example:

```
// Repository application (A) button component
// src/component/button/index.tsx

import { styled, css } from '@/libs/emotion'

// Component implementation...

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3em;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;

  ${Text} + * {
    color: red;
  }
`
```

```
// src/libs/emotion/index.ts
import {
  css,
} from '@emotion/react'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

export {
  css,
  styled,
}
```

While trying to use the packaged component in repository application (B), I encountered the following error:

```
error - Error: Component selectors can only be used in conjunction with @emotion/babel-plugin, the swc Emotion plugin, or another Emotion-aware compiler transform.
```

Although I have already configured Babel in repository application (B) to address the component selector error, I am unsure how to correctly configure the emotion library for the packaged component. When inspecting the transpiled code in the node_modules folder of repository application (B), I noticed that the import path for the Emotion library used by the packaged component is not resolved correctly:

```
// Repository application (B) using the packaged component
// src/component/button/index.jsx

import { styled, css } from '../../libs/emotion'

// Component usage...
```

and this is a The babel.config.js file in repository application (B) contains the following configuration:

```js
// babel.config.js
/** @type {import('@babel/core').TransformOptions} */
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      'next/babel',
      {
        'preset-react': {
          runtime: 'automatic',
          importSource: '@emotion/react',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  plugins: [
    [
      '@emotion/babel-plugin',
      {
        importMap: {
          '@/libs/emotion': {
            styled: {
              canonicalImport: ['@emotion/styled', 'default'],
              styledBaseImport: ['@/libs/emotion', 'styled'],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```

t seems that the absolute path is not being resolved properly, leading to the issue. I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this problem and correctly configure the emotion library for the packaged component in repository application (B).

I tried creating an npm package for a component in repository project (A) that uses the Emotion library. The package was successfully transpiled and published. My expectation was to use this package in repository application (B) without any issues.